# Is it good idea to have many users for one database?

Tags: sql-server

MS SQL SERVER 2008

I have a database. Several operators via my program can interact with it. Each operator have its own name. At present, I create a login and corresponding user name for each operator. Is it good idea ? Number of operators can grow ...

maybe, there's some good practices about it ?

Comment: R u planning to let users access database directly or planning to create each schema for a user?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, just check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745230/sql-server-how-many-users-do-i-really-need

Comment: I'm planning to let users access databse directly. I don't know much about schemas so I don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're are talking about database users... No, that is just a really bad ideia!

Application Users are not the same as Database users. You should really have your user tables with authentication and access control. This is a module of your application.

Database user's and roles and schemas are used to distinguish between functional modules of your projects, to give structure to your enterprise and to separate environments such as testing, pre-production, production and so forth.

Comment: +1 for abstracting concept of Database users and application users. This separation is utmost important in designing applications which make use of database.

Comment: As I understand, there is only one application user with one application role. What about if I want that application user had some database role ?